# read a variable line by line without gobbling the \ character

Tags: bash, quoting

I am using this snippet to read a variable line by line:

```
echo "${lines}" | while read line; do something with ${line}; done
```

`lines` contains new lines and occurrences of the `\` character (the `line` will be interpreted as a `C` string). Unfortunately, somewhere in this code the `\` characters are simply stripped. Why, and how do I fix that?

EDIT:
a sample input is this:

```
foo $'bar'
fee $'ber\fbir'
```

note that only the `\` is stripped, not the `$''` which will be used later to interpret the string as a `C` string.

Comment: the shell is responsible for expanding variables, which means any escapes in `${line}` will be stripped off as the script is processed. if you want the escapes to survive the shell, you'll have to escape the escapes.

Comment: Like @jordanm's answer says, you are looking for `read -r`. His answer seems to be deleted at the moment, though.

Comment: The canonical answer is `while IFS= read -r line; ...`. Also, since you're using bash, use a here string: `while ... done <<< "$lines"`

Comment: @tripleee Yes, I deleted my answer because I thought that I had interpreted the question wrong. Turns out my interpretation was correct, and I should have left it up. Nelson has it covered now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape your `\` characters so they are still present in your `read line`, like this:

```
echo "${lines}" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' | while read line; do something with ${line}; done
```

**UPDATE**: I've just updated the sed line above after some testing, try it now, it's working for me.

**UPDATE 2**: As it seems jordanm deleted his answer which was using a better approach than mine, I'll add it here myself:

Using the `-r` parameter to the `read` command, it instructs it to don't escape the slashes, so this would also work:

```
echo "${lines}" | while read -r line; do something with ${line}; done
```

Comment: @jordanm Your solution is better, didn't know about `read -r`, anyway mine can still be useful as it shows an alternative way, when I post questions I like to have different solutions, and I appreciate any of them, hope OP's think like me ..

Comment: Ey Lorenzo, I'm glad this worked for you, also consider upvoting the answer if you're happy with it :-)